# How can I get Current Local Time in California, United States using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I searched that by doing like this I can get time zone of any country

```
var la = moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ');
```

but when I do for `California` it say no time zone available ?

running fiddle [running example](http://jsfiddle.net/wcu21kr5/115/)

```
SOLUTION :America/Tijuana  have same timezone as America/California
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/loading-a-data-bundle/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `California` is not a valid [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Also from [the moment-timezone docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/):

> The `moment.tz` constructor takes all the same arguments as the moment constructor, but uses the last argument as a *time zone identifier*.

What do you do? Use `America/Los_Angeles`, or any other identifier that is in the same time zone you need.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to be checking out :) `console.log(moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ'));` for right now logs `2017-07-25 09:56:09-07:00`, which I believe is correct?

Comment: @ephemeral [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/loading-a-data-bundle/) uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Los_Angeles`). `California` is **not** one of those valid names, that's why it's not available as a timezone.
`America/Los_Angeles` **already gives you** the current date and time in California. One of the criteria of IANA for a zone name is to get a "major" city of a region to represent the whole region, so `America/Los_Angeles` corresponds to California.

Comment: Thank you for help. I atlast found same time zone. And kindly upvote my question as I have so many negative votes. thank you for help